# Populating dropdown list from json

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, parsing, get

I'm trying to populate parent/child dropdown lists into my HTML form.The dropdown lists have to contain cars/models that are loaded from a json file which looks like this :

```
[{"value":"ACURA","title":"Acura","models":
    [{"value":"CL_MODELS","title":"CL Models (4)"},
    {"value":"2.2CL","title":" - 2.2CL"},
    {"value":"2.3CL","title":" - 2.3CL"},
    {"value":"MDX","title":"MDX"},
    {"value":"NSX","title":"NSX"},
    {"value":"RDX","title":"RDX"},
    {"value":"ACUOTH","title":"Other Acura Models"}]},
{"value":"ALFA","title":"Alfa Romeo","models":[{"value":"ALFA164","title":"164"},
    {"value":"ALFA8C","title":"8C Competizione"},
    {"value":"ALFAGT","title":"GTV-6"},
    {"value":"MIL","title":"Milano"},
    {"value":"SPID","title":"Spider"},
    {"value":"ALFAOTH","title":"Other Alfa Romeo Models"}]}]
```

And for populating I'm trying smth like this :

```
    $.getJSON("textfile.txt", function( json )
    $.each(json, function(key, value) {
    $('select[name=cars]').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + json[key] + '</option>');
}); 



<select name="cars"></select>
<select name="models"></select>
```

But it doesn't even want to show me the cars whats left for the models... I am assuming , I'm not navigating it correctly, beacuse from the example i got this code it is working properly, which i got from here https://www.techenclave.com/community/threads/populate-a-drop-down-list-from-a-text-file.147816/

I hope this info is enough. Thank you in advance !

Comment: Not sure is it a typo, but json format is not valid, you are missing closing bracket... ']' at the end?

Comment: The bracket is not the problem. Thank you for your observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a typo in your JavaScript?  Try out this updated code, with comments for explanation:

```
$.getJSON("textfile.txt", function( json ) {  // Missing this curly brace.
  $.each(json, function(key, value) {
    // Change key and json[key] to json[key].value and json[key].title
    $('select[name=cars]').append('<option value="' + json[key].value + '">' + json[key].title + '</option>');
  }); 
});  // Are you missing this as well?
```

Try the Chrome Console (F12), or Firebug to check for JavaScript errors.  You could also try `console.log(json)` to verify that you are really getting what you expect from your server.

Note that in your example, `json` will be an array containing two objects, each with three properties: value, title, and models.  Each `models` property, in turn will be an array of objects, each with two properties, value and title.

Just for fun I decided to build you a little extra code.  You can see the full fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/zzr9om38/

```
$.each(json, function(key, data) {
    $('select[name=cars]').append('<option value="' + json[key].value + '" data-index="'+key+'">' + json[key].title + '</option>')
});

$('select[name=cars]').change(function(obj){
    var selectedIndex = $(this).find(":selected").attr("data-index");
    $('select[name=models]').find("option:gt(0)").remove();
    if(selectedIndex != undefined) {
        $.each(json[selectedIndex].models, function(key, data) {
            $('select[name=models]').append('<option value="' + json[selectedIndex].models[key].value + '">' + json[selectedIndex].models[key].title + '</option>')
        });
    }
});
```